# open page in new tab in asp.net on clicking a dynamically generated link button in gridview using vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to open the **url** in new tab when clicking on the **link button** that is generated dynamically in grid view. I am using VB. response.redirect(url as string) opens the url in same window. what should i write in on click event????

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using a `LinkButton`, you should use a `Hyperlink` for this kind of link, which `Target` set to `_blank`.

If you need to do some scripting before the new tab is opened, set your Hyperlink's `NavigateUrl` to a generic handler file passing query string variables.

Then after the  script has ran, on the generic handler file, use `Response.Redirect()` to redirect this new tabbed window to the page which you require.

**GridView:**

```
<asp:hyperlinkfield text="Details..."
            navigateurl='<%# String.Format("GenHan.ashx?id={0}", Eval("ID")) %>'            
            headertext="Order Details"
            target="_blank" />
```

**GenHan.ashx:**

```
Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    'Some scripting here....
    Response.Redirect("Final URL here")
End Sub
```

Comment: Private Sub addlink(ByVal grdself As GridView)
        Try
           For Each row As GridViewRow In grdself.Rows
                Dim lnkbtn_print As New LinkButton()
                lnkbtn_print.ID = "lnkbtn_print" & row.RowIndex
                lnkbtn_print.Text = ""
                lnkbtn_print.Text = row.Cells(4).Text
                AddHandler lnkbtn_print.Command, AddressOf lnkbtn_print_click
                lnkbtn_print.CausesValidation = False
                row.Cells(4).Controls.Add(lnkbtn_print)
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub'

Answer (score 0):

try like this. add this code to your link button, in your case add in RowDataBound Event.

```
yourlinkButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('yourUrl'); return false;);
```